# Using random number generator and percentages?

Tags: ruby, random

Is there a better way to write this code?

I want 47.37 percent of the time the number should be "odd". 47.37 percent of the time the number should be "even".

```
random_no = rand*100
if (random_no <= 47.37)
  number = "odd"
elsif (random_no <= 94.74)
  number = "even"
else
  number = "other"
end
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, Zach.  If speed were important, you might consider using integers: `random_no = rand(10_000); if (random_no < 4737)...`.  `rand(10_000)` produces a pseudo-random number between 0 and 9,999, of which there are 4,737 possibilities between 0 and 4736, inclusive.  Hence `<` rather than `<=`.

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity, what is the number if it isn't odd or even? Is this when the coin lands on its edge?? :-) (Edit: Beat me to it Dave)

Comment: I'm not sure if you're also including stylistic things but you can drop the parentheses and you should use indenting. Here is the [github style guide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby) for more info.

Comment: @Dave & Kai: the house gets 5.26%.  That's the standard rate for coin-flipping.

Comment: Ah, profit = 'other'. Gotcha.

Comment: Then I'd argue this might be the wrong approach. Let it be random, and just check for house victory.

Comment: thanks. "other" is the numbers on a blackjack table that aren't odd or even. my friend has this theory that there's a solution to roulette where you aways win. it turns out he is right - but only if there is no maximum bet. thank you for the help

Comment: @DaveNewton, id like to use the number variable that is assigned

Comment: oops. roulette, not blackjack

Comment: Ah, in that case you could always just use `rand(38)`, and take 37 to mean '00', or some variation of that. I think that's what Dave might have been suggesting. You can easily test for odd or even using `Integer#odd?` and `Integer#even?`

Comment: If I were creating a roulette game, I'd make a new Roulette class, which is capable of spinning a number, reporting whether it was odd or even, whether the house wins, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Vidaica's answer if you're going for a one liner. But why? I think your code is easier to understand. Alternatively you could save three lines by using a case statement:

```
number = case rand*100
when 0...47.37 then 'odd'
when 47.37...94.74 then 'even'
else 'other'
end
```

I also like Cary's comment, about using integers for performance. You could combine that with any of the above solutions.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a solution:

```
{'odd'=> 47.37, 'even'=> 94.74, 'other'=> 100}
.find{|key, value| rand* 100 <= value}.first
```

Answer (score 2):

Now that I know it's for a roulette game, I'd go about it differently, using rand(38) to pick a number and then seeing whether it's odd, even or 'other'. To illustrate an OO approach to this:

```
class Roulette
  def initialize
    spin
  end
  def spin
    @number_showing = rand(38)
  end
  def odd_even?
    if @number_showing == 0 || @number_showing == 37
      return 'other'
    elsif @number_showing.odd?
      return 'odd'
    else
      return 'even'
    end
  end
  def number_showing
    if @number_showing == 37
      return '00'
    else
      return @number_showing.to_s
    end
  end
end

wheel = Roulette.new

10.times do
  wheel.spin
  puts wheel.number_showing
  puts wheel.odd_even?
  puts
end
```